# C++ std::bad_alloc error with std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, bad-alloc, clion

I understand this question has been asked before, but the answers seemed too specified towards the asker's code.

If this is considered a useless duplicate question feel free to remove it or mark it as a duplicate.

As far as I can tell, my code is correct for what I am trying to achieve, which is counting the number of occurrences of specified words in a text file. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

**The Error**

```
    This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

**Part of my main.cpp (Causing the problem)**

```
    //vectors to hold words from two files
vector<string> wordlist;
vector<string> file;
vector<int> searchVec;

//while a is not an empty string
while (a != "") {

    //getNextWord() returns each word in order from a text file
    //a is a play script, b is a list of words to search for
    a = infile.getNextWord();
    b = infile2.getNextWord();

    file.push_back(a);

    //counts total words in play script
    count++;

    //increments and adds each word from the list of words to search for to the vector
    for (int i = 0; b != ""; i++) {

        wordlist.push_back(b);

    }

    //cycles through words to search for
    for (int j = 0; j < wordlist.size(); j++) {

        //cycle through te play script
        for (int k = 0; k < file.size(); k++) {

            //if the current play script word is the same as the test word, up the count
            if (file[k] == wordlist[j]) {

                searchCount++;

            }

        }

        //print appropriate output, re-initialise the count to 0 for the next word
        cout << "The word " << wordlist[j] << " occurs " << searchCount << " times." << endl;

        searchCount = 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging this through your debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you think this loop terminates?:

```
for (int i = 0; b != ""; i++) {

    wordlist.push_back(b);

}
```

Comment: Sorry that was wrong, my function getNextWord() actually returns an empty string when the file reaches the end.

Comment: `b`'s value is not changing inside the loop. So this is an infinite loop. Add a sample `cout` statement inside this loop to confirm.